# Amazon S3 - Get Object .NET C# Error

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I am working on some .NET C# implementation and am running into issues.

I've been working with a set of code that looks similar to the following:

```
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("id", "key", "region");
TransferUtility transfer = new TransferUtility(client);

TransferUtilityDownloadRequest request = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
request.BucketName = "bucketName";
request.Key = "keyName";
request.FilePath = destinationPath;

try {
    await transfer.DownloadAsync(request);
} catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception) {
    if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
        (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
        ||
        amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
    {
        throw new Exception("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
    } else  {
        throw new Exception("Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message);
    }
} catch (TypeLoadException e)  {
    Debug.WriteLine("caught some weird bug: " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

However after the file successfully downloads from the server it catches the TypeLoadException thrown from the DownloadAsync function and states the following:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Could not load type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.DecryptStream' from assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.Internal.DownloadCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyApp.StartPage.<download>d__20.MoveNext() in C:\...\StartPage.xaml.cs:line 295

Inner Exception 1:
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.DecryptStream' from assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'.
```

I'm not even using AWSSDK.Core version 3.3.0.0; I am using version 3.3.13.2 which is bundled in with AWSSDK.S3 version 3.3.5.15 from NuGet.

I'm not sure how to proceed since this error is thrown no matter what version of AWS I use and it doesn't matter if the content on the S3 is encrypted or not.

Comment: Looks like the DecryptStream is not available as per below http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_Runtime_Internal_Util.htm

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. If the AmazonServiceException is caught, the file will save correctly. Apparently it does not matter that the app can't find the DecryptStream type.

Just change the:

```
} catch (TypeLoadException e)  {
```

to

```
} catch (AmazonServiceException e)  {
```

in order to properly catch the exception and continue with the rest of the code.